# Является ли эта переменная js массивом?

Tags: javascript

Имеется некоторая таблица состоящая из  и  тэгов, к которой обращается код

```js
let tr_list = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (let i = 0; i < tr_list.length; i++) {
 let a = tr_list[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
 
 
}
```

Вопрос является ли переменная a массивом?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот код пробегается по таблице и заносит каждый первый  от каждого  в массив a? таким образом выделяя столбец? Ну и наконец, как сделать какое нибудь простое взаимодействие с выделенными данными и присвоить им например какой нибудь css стиль? Просто я как ни пытаюь взаимодействовать теперь с массивом/переменной a, но при этом всё время выдаёт какую нибудь ошибку (Я только учусь не бейте палками за эти вопросы) Ещё вопрос является ли такой код работающим?

Comment: чтобы узнать является ли результат работы функции массивом нужно открыть документацию по данной функции и посмотреть тип возвращаемого результата.

Comment: нет не является.

Comment: можете проверить - `Array.isArray`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName > `Element.getElementsByTagName()` метод возвращает живую коллекцию элементов `HTMLCollection`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection > `HTMLCollection`, хранящая элементы DOM ...